Correct breaker for electrical panel
I am installing a dedicated circuit for a bathroom outlet. Attached is a picture of the old Sylvania panel.

My understanding from looking at this is that this panel does accept tandem breakers seeing as it is a “20/40” panel.

Can I use the breaker pictured? It says that it is type A which the panel lists as acceptable. Is this actually acceptable? And should I be using a CTL rated breaker or a non-CTL breaker?

Please use the [edit] link underneath your post to update it with new information. Thanks and welcome to the site!

Yup, Challenger type C and Eaton Type C are one and the same.  When BRyant designed their type BR panel, they used Challenger/Sylvania's perfectly excellent bus design.  There was a scandal with type C breakers not tripping when they should, so they renamed the panel type BR to forbid real type C's. But BR is cross-listed type C.  Wise to replace all breakers with BR/C and BRD/A.
